# Selecting and Dragging tiles

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a game that involves clicking and dragging tiles to create a path, similar to the popular game [Flow Free.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J1Vp.png)

I want to be able to select a tile and slide my finger all in one swipe, however I am having some issues.
I have tried using SwipeGestures, in that

```
// listen for swipes to the left
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeLeft= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
// listen for swipes to the right
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRight= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
// listen for swipes up
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeUp= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp)];
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
// listen for swipes down
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeDown= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown)];
swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];
```

My problem is that SwipeGestures only recognize one swipe per screen press -- If I change directions, mid swipe, it does not register.

Assuming that I will need to use UIGestureRecognizers, is it possible for me to use a PanGestureRecognizer along with a SwipeGestureRecognizer to continually check for changes in directions of swipes?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because you are passing a different method for each swipe direction instead of letting UIPanGestureRecognizer detect the swipe direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assessment: `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is not really useful for this because it only *recognizes* once the swipe has finished.

What you want is to track the item while the swipe is occurring, you'd use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and track each movement.

To track which direction, you can do something similar to this:

```
- (void)onPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan) {
  CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:[pan view]];
  if (translation.x > 0) {
     // moving right...
  }

  // important to "eat" the translation if you've handled the
  // UI changes, otherwise the translation will keep accumulating
  // across multiple calls to this method
  [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[pan view]];
```

}

Hope this helps.